# how to display a comment in matlab when it runs a python code ?

Tags: python, matlab, abaqus

With the help of interfacing ABAQUS and Matlab, I plan to optimize the parametric model in ABAQUS. In this regard, parametric optimization required the Python programming language (as the main language of ABAQUS ). At the time of the linking process of MATLAB, the Python code is called, and until the code is completed, no notation of the problem-solving displayed in the MATLAB window, and the user should wait without informing about the time of completion of the analysis. is this a way to solve this problem?

Comment: you need to show examples of the matlab and python code. There is no way to answer this with the info provided.

Comment: there isn't exist any code. the python and MATLAB are two software which I use for my problem, and the question have nothing about the code. I want to run a code (no matter what !) in python from MATLAB and I want to show me how much percent of the python code ran with a comment which python displays in Matlab window.

Comment: are you saying there isn't some sort of function call within matlab that invokes the python program? How does it work then?